# template friend function overloading

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading the `std::enable_shared_from_this`(g++ version) source code in the past two days. There is two questions confuse me.
Let me show brief source code first.

```
template<typename _Tp>
class enable_shared_from_this {
...
private:
    template<typename _Tp1>
    friend void
    __enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<>& __pn,
        const enable_shared_from_this* __pe,
        const _Tp1* __px) noexcept {
        }
};

template<typename _Tp1, typename _Tp2>
void
__enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<>&,
        const enable_shared_from_this<_Tp1>*,
        const _Tp2*) noexcept;
```

Questions:
 1. note the line `const enable_shared_from_this* __pe`, there is no tag '<>' after `enable_shared_from_this`, does this imply `enable_shared_from_this<__Tp1>` here?
 2. There is two overload function template `__enable_shared_from_this_helper` here, my test shows that the version defined in `class enable_shared_from_this` will always be called, why?

Thank you guys, would appreciate any effort.

Answer (score 0):

For 1.: No, it means that the `<_Tp>` is implicit here, not the `<_Tp1>` from the additional template parameter. When you leave out the template parameters of the class name within the definition of a class (or the body of a member-method's definition), and a type is expected, the parameters from the class itself are implied.

For 2.: This is the same as the first one just with `_Tp1` instead of `_Tp` and with `_Tp2` instead of `_Tp1`.